# How to install libmeanwhile1 version 1.0.2-4.1ubuntu1 from Ubuntu Utopic while running Ubuntu Vivid?

Tags: package-management, 15.04

I really need the older version of this library, and just this library. Please advise how to downgrade and lock the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the Utopic package, install and set on hold

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/m/meanwhile/libmeanwhile1_1.0.2-4.1ubuntu1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libmeanwhile1_1.0.2-4.1ubuntu1_i386.deb
sudo apt-mark hold libmeanwhile1
```

---

Check it

```
% sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libmeanwhile1
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

---

To reverse the behaviour

```
sudo apt-mark unhold libmeanwhile1
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

---

Note, there are some packages which depends on `libmeanwhile1`

```
% apt-cache rdepends libmeanwhile1           
libmeanwhile1
Reverse Depends:
  kopete
  libpurple0
  libmeanwhile-dev
```